# how to send text as an input and receive sentiment or emotion as a response in azure API?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, azure-cognitive-services, azure-api-apps, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I would like to implement a python script in an azure API. Basically, I would like to send text and receive emotion or sentiment. I am assuming that the API is the writing approach or is it a web app?
Would you be able to direct me to documentation with an example? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [Azure Text Analytics API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/) could meet your requirement, this API provides you with Analyze sentiment functionality and associated python SDK. You can try the code below to get started with python SDK V2 [sentiment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-language-textanalytics/azure.cognitiveservices.language.textanalytics.textanalyticsclient?view=azure-python#sentiment-show-stats-none--documents-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) function:

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.language.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

subscriptionKey = "<YOUR AZURE COGNITIVE SERVICE KEY>"
endpoint = "<YOUR AZURE COGNITIVE SERVICE SERVICE ENDPOINT>"


credentials = CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscriptionKey)

text_analytics = TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint=endpoint, credentials=credentials)

documents = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "language": "en",
        "text": "I had the best day of my life."
    }
]
response = text_analytics.sentiment(documents=documents)
for document in response.documents:
    print("Document Id: ", document.id, ", Sentiment Score: ",
          "{:.2f}".format(document.score))
```

Result:
[image]

You can find your service endpoint  and subscriptionKey on Azure portal:

[image]

After you [Create a Cognitive Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account?tabs=multiservice%2Cwindows) on Azure portal.

You can deploy your application on the Azure app service, for how to do it, just refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=bash&pivots=python-framework-flask).

Comment: thank you for your reply. this is the perfect solution. but small change is my query as I have written my own code in python which can help me to identify the sentiment of text which I can pass as an input. Wanted to implement this in azure environment so can I use app service for this it will help me to maintain some abstraction with my code

Comment: @Pakard, glad to know it is helpful : )